# Why did I got so many cloudwatch metrics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-billing

Today, I check my AWS Bill, surprisingly I used so many cloudwatch metrics: 78.023 Metrics

[image]

But when I check all metrics in Cloudwatch console, it shows only 1,992 metrics available in that region (us-east-1)

[image]

Can someone explain to me why I have so many metrics? and where are other metrics which are not in cloudwatch console metric?
Thank you.

I checked many links about cloudwatch metrics but I cannot find the reason

Comment: `30c x 78 metric-months = $23.40` A 'metric-month' is one metric for a whole month. So, while you have 1992 different metrics, it was only calculated as 78 whole-months for metrics. Perhaps you are incorrectly reading `78.023` as `78,023`?

Comment: omg, I didn't think metrics can be decimal number. Thank you for pointing me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 78 metrics => There are custom metrics for which you must pay money. It is CWAgent item in your photo. If you run resources for 1 month, the metrics number value in the Billing is 98.
- 1992 metrics => There are default metrics for which you mustn't pay money. You  only must pay money when enabling monitoring detail (collect metrics with period each minute)